# Spring RestController returns 400 Bad Requests for POST Request (used @RequestBody)

Tags: spring, post

I have a simple code snippet below (I did not extends existing repository interface, just try to do things in memory). The GET request works but the POST request returned 400 Bad Request.

I send JSON data to the localhost:8080/v1/products in the below format

```
{
        "productId": 4,
        "name": "Amazon Alexa",
        "price": 500.0,
        "description": "AI device"
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class ProductController {

    private ProductRepository productRepo;
    
    private ProductController(ProductRepository productRepo) {
        this.productRepo = productRepo;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> getProduct() {
        return productRepo.findAllProducts();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> postProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return productRepo.saveProduct(product);
    }
}
```

Repository class

```
@Repository
public class ProductRepository {
    
    Boolean isLoaded = false;
    Product product1 = new Product(1, "Apple TV", 300.0, "This is a TV");
    Product product2 = new Product(2, "Samsung Tablet", 900.0, "This is on sale");
    Product product3 = new Product(3, "Google Home", 100.0, "Smart AI device");
    
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    
    private void loadProducts() {
        if (!isLoaded) {
            products.add(product1);
            products.add(product2);
            products.add(product3); 
            isLoaded = true;
        }
    }
    
    public List<Product> findAllProducts() {
        loadProducts();
        return products;
    }
    
    public List<Product> saveProduct(Product product) {
        loadProducts();
        products.add(product);
        return products;
    }
}
```

Product class with getters/setters omitted, all argument constructor omitted

```
public class Product {

    private int productId;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private String description;

}
```

Does anyone know what I missed? Thanks

Comment: does class `Product` has default no arguments constructor? If no, can you add one and try to make post request one more time.

Comment: You are correct, adding a no argument constructor makes the POST request work. But there is a new problem. The output I get will be of default data types, for example:

    {
        "productId": 0,
        "name": null,
        "price": 0.0,
        "description": null
    }

Comment: Is the output with default values returned also for existing products? Can you also check is  `product` send to POST method contains json send values?

Comment: the existing products have non-default values, only the newly sent product returned as default value. Yes, I choose to send json format in Postman